# How can I delete a data on db automatically after 24 hours in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to make an instagram clone with django. I'm trying to make stories of instagram on Django Models.As you know, instagrams stories are deleted after 24 hours. How can i delete data from database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just filter these out. You can make a model that looks like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

then you can retrieve only `MyModel` objects that are at most 24 hours old with:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models.functions import Now

MyModel.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=Now()-timespan(days=1))
```

you can occasionally run a management command that removes the old `MyModel`s with:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models.functions import Now

MyModel.objects.filter(timestamp__lt=Now()-timespan(days=1)).delete()
```

Comment: and maybe automate it with https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat